# (Visual studio,.net, aws) -Error when publishing to aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have the following error:

```
API.Usuario -> C:\Users\Guilherme Campos\Meus Projetos\BlackJack\Back-end\API.Usuario\bin\Release\net6.0\linux-x64\API.Usuario.dll
(x86)\dotnet\sdk\6.0.412\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.CrossGen.targets(464,5): error :    at ILCompiler.Program.RunSingleCompilation(Dictionary`2 inFilePaths, InstructionSetSupport instructionSetSupport, String compositeRootPath, Dictionary`2 unrootedInputFilePaths, HashSet`1 versionBubbleModulesHash, CompilerTypeSystemContext typeSystemContext) [C:\Users\Guilherme Campos\Meus Projetos\BlackJack\Back-end\API.Usuario\API.Usuario.csproj]
... publish: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\6.0.412\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.CrossGen.targets(464,5): error :    at ILCompiler.Program.Run(String[] args) [C:\Users\Guilherme Campos\Meus Projetos\BlackJack\Back-end\API.Usuario\API.Usuario.csproj]
... publish: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\6.0.412\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.CrossGen.targets(464,5): error :    at ILCompiler.Program.Main(String[] args) [C:\Users\Guilherme Campos\Meus Projetos\BlackJack\Back-end\API.Usuario\API.Usuario.csproj]
... publish: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\6.0.412\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.CrossGen.targets(352,5): error NETSDK1096: Optimizing assemblies for performance failed. You can either exclude the failing assemblies from being optimized, or set the PublishReadyToRun property to false. [C:\Users\Guilherme Campos\Meus Projetos\BlackJack\Back-end\API.Usuario\API.Usuario.csproj]
ERROR: The dotnet publish command return unsuccessful error code
Error packaging up project in C:\Users\Guilherme Campos\Meus Projetos\BlackJack\Back-end\API.Usuario\. for CloudFormation resource AspNetCoreFunction: ERROR: The dotnet publish command return unsuccessful error code
```

What should I do in this case?

I was hoping that I would have to change the version, I made the change and nothing

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using ahead-of-time compilation, but some of the libraries in your project are not eligible for it.

As mentioned in the error message, you have two options to resolve the issue:

1. When publishing the code, do not use ahead-of-time compilation:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishReadyToRun=false
```

2. Or, exclude the DLLs that are not eligible for ahead-of-time compilation:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PublishReadyToRunExclude Include="unsupported-libray.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```